# Increase array amount without resetting it (Javascript/Canvas)

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

In my project, I want my array to increase in size every 5 seconds. I tried to use setInterval to call a function to do this, but it resets my array every 5 seconds with an increased amount rather than naturally growing. Is there a way to increase the amount without having to reset the array each time?

These are the functions I am using to call my "plants":

```
var myPlants = new Array();
var plantSpawn = 0;

function createPlants() {

    reproducePlants();

    setInterval(reproducePlants, 5000);

}   

function reproducePlants() {
    plantSpawn += 5;

    for(var i=0; i<plantSpawn; i++){

        var rr = Math.round(Math.random() * 150);
        var gg = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
        var bb = Math.round(Math.random() * 150);

        var plant = new Object();
            plant.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
            plant.y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
            plant.rad = 2;
            plant.skin = 'rgba('+rr+','+gg+','+bb+', 1)';

        myPlants[i] = plant;

    }
}
```

Comment: Currently it updates the already existing *plants* every time. If you just want to add 5 new elements, run `for` loop 5 times (`i < 5`) and use `myPlants.push(plant)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are explicitly reseting all the values of the array when you do this:

```
for(var i=0; i < plantSpawn; i++){... myPlants[i] = plant; ...}
```

Note that `plantSpawn` will hold the new array size, so you are looping over all the old indexes plus the new ones and re-assigning the values on they.

So, instead you can add `5` new elements to the array with [Array.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) this way:

```
var myPlants = new Array();
var plantsInc = 5;

function createPlants()
{
    reproducePlants();
    setInterval(reproducePlants, 5000);
}

function reproducePlants()
{
    // Push N new plants on the array.

    for (var i = 0; i < plantsInc; i++)
    {
        var rr = Math.round(Math.random() * 150);
        var gg = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
        var bb = Math.round(Math.random() * 150);

        var plant = new Object();
        plant.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
        plant.y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
        plant.rad = 2;
        plant.skin = 'rgba('+rr+','+gg+','+bb+', 1)';

        // Push a new plant on the array.
        myPlants.push(plant);
    }
}
```

And as a suggestion, you can even wrap the logic to create a new plant inside a method, like this:

```
var myPlants = new Array();
var plantsInc = 5;

function createPlants()
{
    reproducePlants();
    setInterval(reproducePlants, 5000);
}

function createPlant()
{
    var rr = Math.round(Math.random() * 150);
    var gg = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    var bb = Math.round(Math.random() * 150);

    var plant = new Object();
    plant.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
    plant.y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
    plant.rad = 2;
    plant.skin = 'rgba('+rr+','+gg+','+bb+', 1)';
    return plant;
}

function reproducePlants()
{
    // Push N new plants on the array.

    for (var i = 0; i < plantsInc; i++)
    {
        myPlants.push(createPlant());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding all the existing values so instead of using  `myPlants[i] = plant;` use `myPlants.push(plant)`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to modify your function to add a plant onto an existing array, rather than looping over your array and assigning it new values.

if you want to add a new value to your array every 5 seconds, something like this should work:

```
var myPlants = new Array();
var plantSpawn = 0;

function createPlants() {

     reproducePlants();

     setInterval(reproducePlants, 5000);

}   

function reproducePlants() {

    var rr = Math.round(Math.random() * 150);
    var gg = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    var bb = Math.round(Math.random() * 150);

    var plant = new Object();
    plant.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
    plant.y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
    plant.rad = 2;
    plant.skin = 'rgba('+rr+','+gg+','+bb+', 1)';

    myPlants.push(plant);
}
```

This just adds a new plant to the end of your array rather than assigning new values to your current array each time you call your function. From here you should be able to put that into a for loop if you wanted to add more plants than 1 at a time. each iteration of the loop will only add a single plan to your array.